# Server certificate verification failed

Tags: ssl

I'm running into a rather confusing issue with server certificate verifications. When running `apt update` I get the following error:

```
W: Failed to fetch https://deb.nodesource.com/node_6.x/dists/trusty/main/binary-amd64/Packages  server certificate verification failed. CAfile: none CRLfile: none
W: Failed to fetch https://packages.gitlab.com/gitlab/gitlab-ce/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/source/Sources  server certificate verification failed. CAfile: none CRLfile: none
```

And also when I try to clone a Git repository, I get:
`fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/certbot/certbot/': server certificate verification failed. CAfile: none CRLfile: none`

The operating system is Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS.

I tried reinstalling the `ca-certificates` and adding extra certificates from other sources and updating the certificates by running `update-ca-certificates`.

This problem just happened to spontaneously appear from all I could tell.

Hopefully somebody can help me out with this. Thanks!

Comment: You have to contact the maintainer of those git repos.

Comment: I have a similar error on a github repository https://github.com/ambv/black I can't reproduce yet outside my complicated usecase (ubuntu + guix + pipenv + pre-commit + git)

Answer (score 0):

I managed to work around the issue my specifically ignoring server certificate verification for now in APT. By adding some custom configuration in `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d`.

In case of Gitlab:
`Acquire::https::packages.gitlab.com::Verify-Peer "false";`

For the Git issues I used the `GIT_SSL_NO_VERIFY` environment variable whenever accessing the repository.

It's not a solution per se, but this way I can at least keep using the repo's. :-)